# regex to allow only numbers and single dot in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

Regex to allow only numbers and single dot when entering number to textbox in jquery.

Please suggest any regex to allow only numbers and single dot in textbox.

I have tried the following code.

```
$("#amountId").val().replace( /[^0-9]+/g, '')
```

Comment: "Single dot" Do you mean `123.` or `123.123` ?

Comment: Your question is unclear, please provide examples of valid and invalid inputs.

Answer (score 5):

`[-+]?([0-9]*\.[0-9]+|[0-9]+)`.

See [Matching Floating Point Numbers With Regex](http://www.regular-expressions.info/floatingpoint.html)

Answer (score 1):

This will find something like this `1234.5678`
`/\d+\.\d+/`

Answer (score 0):

This regex should do the trick for you, `\d+\.$`, and here is a [Rubular to prove it](http://rubular.com/r/Rm57gvksob). You could even consider prefacing the string with the `^` so that nothing can come before the digits too, like this, `^\d+\.$`.

Answer (score 0):

I would try using the following:

```
\d+\.\d?{2}
```

http://rubular.com/r/a83BWznDuy